# Дефолтное значение для табличного типа

Tags: sql-server

Использую в хранимке табличный тип:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_TestProc
@UID INT =0,
@RequredID StringTableType READONLY
```

Где StringTableType табличный тип определяемый следующим образом:

```
 CREATE TYPE dbo.StringTableType AS TABLE (
  StrValue VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
  )
```

Вопрос: Как сделать параметр @RequredID необязательным?

Или, как альтернатива: Как определить для @RequredID значение по умолчанию? (не пустое, а скажем чтобы таблице была одна строка со значением "EMPTY")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные табличного типа итак необязательны.

Можно вызвать:

```
exec dbo.p_TestProc @UID = 1
```

в этом случае `@RequiredID` примет значение пустой таблицы.

Значение по умолчанию, насколько мне известно, задать нельзя, т.е. написать что-то типа

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_TestProc
(
    @UID INT = 0,
    @RequiredID StringTableType READONLY = VALUES ('EMPTY')
)
```

не выйдет.

Если нет возможности контролировать вызов процедуры, то можно внутри кода процедуры вместо входного параметра попробовать использовать дополнительную переменную того же табличного типа, в которую перекладывать данные из входного параметра, или инициализировать её по необходимости значениями по-умолчанию. Примерно так:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.p_TestProc
(
    @UID INT = 0,
    @RequiredID StringTableType READONLY
)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare @NormalizedID StringTableType;

    if exists (select 1 from @RequiredID)
        insert into @NormalizedID (StrValue)
        select StrValue from @RequiredID;
    else
        insert into @NormalizedID (StrValue)
        values ('EMPTY');

    -- далее по коду использовать @NormalizedID вместо @RequiredID
    -- ...
end
```

Хотя, конечно такое перекладывание данных не слишком изящно и несколько снизит производительность.

Если же вы контролируете вызов, то оптимальнее всё же задать умолчания *до вызова* процедуры, а не внутри неё.

В SQL коде это будет примерно так:

```
declare @uid int;
declare @tableParam dbo.StringTableType;

select @uid = ID from SomeTable where ...;

insert into @tableParam (StrValue)
select SomeValue
from SomeOtherTable
where ...;

if not exists (select 1 from @tableParam)
    insert into @tableParam (StrValue)
    values ('EMPTY');

exec dbo.p_TestProc @uid, @tableParam;
```

Если же это внешний вызов, то, например, на C# это будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

```
class StringTableType : DataTable
{
    public StringTableType()
    {
        Columns.Add("StrValue", typeof(string));
    }

    public static StringTableType GetDefault()
    {
        var def = new StringTableType();
        def.Rows.Add("EMPTY");

        return def;
    }
}

void Call_p_TestProc(int? uid, StringTableType t)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.p_TestProc");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", uid ?? (object)DBNull.Value);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@tableParam", SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            TypeName = "[dbo].[StringTableType]",
            Value = t == null || t.Rows.Count == 0 ? StringTableType.GetDefault() : t
        });

    //execute cmd
}
```

Comment: Я для работы с базой использую dbForge Studio. и если я пытаюсь в ней вызвать хранимую процедуру то она мне ругается если я оставляю поле @RequredID пустым. Говорит, что значение не может быть DBNull

Comment: А так да, при вызове хранимки в коде значение действительно не требуется. PS: Я немного уточнил вопрос...

Comment: @Alexey, расширил ответ.

Comment: оптимальнее всё-таки было бы конечно задать умолчания для табличного параметра(ов)  _до вызова_ процедуры, а не внутри неё

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @Alexey, добавил пример.